# Two forms interacting with each other

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have two identical forms that are on separate pages.

**Page 1**

The form on this page is a quick call to action so to speak that will pre populate the form on the next page.

```
<form action="/xxxx" method="post">
    <select id="island" name="island">
        <option selected value="base">Select an Island</option>
        <option value="north-island">North Island</option>
        <option value="south-island">South Island</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Page 2**

As it stands, I can populate the form below using the following:

```
<select id="island" name="island">
    <option value="base">Select an Island</option>
    <option <?php if( isset($_POST['island']) ) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="north-island">North Island</option>
    <option <?php if( isset($_POST['island']) ) { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="south-island">South Island</option>
</select>
```

Now, my problem I have is that I am using AJAX to retrieve data which works fine if I use the form as it is on Page 2 but going from page 1 to page 2 it doesn't pick up the **.change** and therefor the results don't show.

```
$('#island').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'cfd_map',
            option: selectedValue
        },
        url: "xxxxxx",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.results').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone help me out here?

Cheers

Comment: Need to store state change somewhere...server or in localStorage and update `results` accordingly on page load probably. Javscript isn't persistent between page loads

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for reply. Where about's exactly? Only know basic JS. Cheers.

Comment: Try localStorage then. within change handler update localStorage with value. On page load retrieve from storage, set value of select and trigger change event and ajax will run again

Comment: @charlietfl Something like this? localStorage.setItem("'<?php echo $_SESSION['island'];?>'");

Comment: Set method is right... but will need to do it from `selectedValue ` in the jQuery. On page load....use getitem, set the value and right after the change event code do `$('#island').change();`

Comment: Actually this might be even simpler than I was thinking. You only need results carried from page 1 to page 2 and not backwrds to page 1? If that's right answer is really simple

Comment: @charlietfl - The results will only be shown on page 2 however the results need to show if they come from page 1 or page 2... if that makes sense?

Comment: Ok...then need to store for page 1 also. So localStorage would work

Comment: I'm not familiar with localStorage so is it simply adding a line below $('#island').change(function() {

Comment: No...inside it to set and just before it to get the value from storage and set the value of select before my new change trigger takes effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `results` only need to be available going from page 1 to page 2 and not going back to page 1 from page 2 then following will work:

```
$('#island').change(function() {

  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  // only do ajax if there is a value
  if (selectedValue) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'cfd_map',
        option: selectedValue
      },
      url: "xxxxxx",
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      }
    });
  }
  // now trigger change 
}).change();
```

It simply triggers the change after the handler is declared. Triggering the change will then make the ajax call to get results

Since the server already sets value on page 2 there should be no other local storage needed - unless this needs to work both ways

Comment: The results are only ever shown on page 2. The page 1 form is simply a homepage call to action where the user can quickly select and then be redirected to page 2 and be shown the results. If the user decides to skip page 1 and go straight to page 2 they may do so and use the form.

Comment: Well try this solution going from home to page 2 for now. Then can add functionality if needed to go back

Comment: Ok this solution seems to work however it doesn't fade in the results if I use the form on page 2 only? I will give this the correct answer. 

Also, if I select no option from the form on page 1 is still populates the form on page 2 as North Island, why?

Comment: Last part---not sure what is getting stored in session when it is empty